# What is the correct way to define an already existing (e.g. in Prelude) operator between a user-defined type and an existing type?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, operator-overloading, typeclass, primitive-types

Suppose I have a custom type wrapping an existing type,

```hs
newtype T = T Int deriving Show
```

and suppose I want to be able to add up `T`s, and that adding them up should result in adding the wrapped values up; I would do this via

```hs
instance Num T where
  (T t1) + (T t2) = T (t1 + t2)
  -- all other Num's methods = undefined
```

I think we are good so far. Please, tell me if there are major concerns up to this point.

Now let's suppose that I want to be able to multiply a `T` by an `Int` and that the result should be a `T` whose wrapping value is the former multiplied by the int; I would go for something like this:

```hs
instance Num T where
  (T t1) + (T t2) = T (t1 + t2)
  (T t) * k = T (t * k)
  -- all other Num's methods = undefined
```

which obviously doesn't work because `class Num` declares `(*) :: a -> a -> a`, thus requiring the two operands (and the result) to be all of the same type.

Even defining `(*)` as a free function poses a similar problem (i.e. `(*)` exists already in `Prelude`).

How could I deal with this?

As for the why of this question, I can device the following

- in my program I want to use `(Int,Int)` for 2D vectors in a cartesian plane,
- but I also use `(Int,Int)` for another unrelated thing,
- therefore I have to disambiguate between the two, by using a `newtype` for at least one of them or, if use `(Int,Int)` for several other reasons, then why not making all of them `newtype`s wrapping `(Int,Int)`?
- since `newtype Vec2D = Vec2D (Int,Int)` represents a vector in the plain, it makes sense to be able to do `Vec2D (2,3) * 4 == Vec2D (8,12)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very similar examples have been asked often already, and the answer is that this is **not** a number type and therefore should not have a `Num` instance. What it actually is is a [vector space](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space) type, accordingly you should define instead

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.AdditiveGroup
import Data.VectorSpace

newtype T = T Int deriving Show

instance AdditiveGroup T where
  T t1 ^+^ T t2 = T $ t1 + t2
  zeroV = T 0
  negateV (T t) = T $ -t

instance VectorSpace T where
  type Scalar T = Int
  k *^ T t = T $ k * t
```

Then your `T -> Int -> T` operator is [`^*`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.16/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html#v:-94--42-), which is simply `flip (*^)`.

That leads also to the more general what you should do when overloading a standard operator with a different meaning: just make it a *separate* definition. You don't even need to give it a different name, this can also be disambiguated using `qualified` module imports.

Just please don't instantiate classes incompletely, in particular not `Num`. This just leads to php-ish confusion when somebody uses a generic function with those types, it compiles just fine but then horribly breaks at runtime when the calling code expects `Num` semantics but the type fails to actually offer that.

Comment: I'm fairly happy with this answer, but I have a follow-up question: I see that accepting that `T` being not a `Num`ber, and adopting your suggested solution, implies that `(T 3) * 3` cannot (probably _should not_, based on what you write) be made meaningful because at least I have to use another symbol instead of `*`. Is this correct?

Comment: @Enlico If you really want to you can use the symbol `*`, but whether you do or don't use the same symbol it will be entirely unrelated to the existing one. But it's quite a pain to use two unrelated operators with the same name (you'd have to import the Prelude hiding `*` and then write things like `x Prelude.* y` to get to multiplication from `Num`, or do that with your operator). And normal number multiplication is pretty common, so that's not very convenient. So most people decide to simply give operators like this a different name that emphasizes the connection to the original, like `^*`.

Comment: @Ben, then in my previous comment I should have written `((T 3) * 3, 3*3)` instead of just `(T 3) * 3` to make my intention clearer. Based on your comment having that expression being meaningful is not possible. Probably this is just a reflection of the fact that I should not even attempt it, which seems to be in line with the answer we are commenting.

Comment: @Enlico Well, there is one option. Which is to *completely* avoid the Prelude's `*`, and make your own new version that is general enough able to encompass *both* `T 3 * 3` and `3 * 3`. Since the types aren't the same for both of those, it'll require you to make a new class you use instead of `Num` (at least for multiplication), which means you'll have to write instances for the builtin types as well as your new type. I can write an answer if that's something you're interested in, and don't know how to do?

Comment: @Enlico Worth noting, however, that it in no way makes your new type compatible with the existing operator (anyone else who imports your type won't be able to use `*` with it; they'll have to also hide the Prelude's `*` and import your new operator). I've played around with this sort of thing before, and ended up concluding that since Prelude's `*` is fundamentally a different operation from the one I wanted, it's actually nicer to just use a different symbol for it.

Comment: @Ben yeah, I'm getting to the same conclusion. No need for another answer, I guess, as it would express a similar idea as this one.

Comment: @Ben I've [toyed around](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/linearmap-family/blob/master/Math/LinearMap/Category/TensorQuot.hs#L35) with “one to ring to rule them all” _(pun semi-intended)_ multiplication operators as well. You _can_ actually get quite close with a “tensor quotient” type family. The `·` operator subsumes numerical, vector-scaling, and inner-product multiplication, however it's still awkward to use in practice because one of the arguments is a type family that can only be inferred from the other argument _and_ the computation result.